# Adding mouseover attribute in c# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET and in the code behind I need to add an attribute which makes text2 appear when the user puts the mouse over text1; below is what I currently have.

JS:

```
function show(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).visible = true;
    }
```

C#:

```
text2.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "show(" + text2.ClientID +")");
```

HTML:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="text2" Visible="false"/>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="text1" rel="external" />
```

Comment: is there any error you are facing?

Comment: Make sure you don't confuse asp.net server properties with `css` properties.  `visibility=true` is an asp.net server property, which is resolved before the page is rendered.  javascript has no knowledge of these properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things here:

1. `Visible="false"` is not a styling, it is a server-side property. Setting it false means that the control won't be rendered at all. So it won't even exist on the client side, and of course there is no way to access it via javascript. Instead consider assigning a `CSS` class to it or, at the very least, inline style like `style="visibility: hidden"`
2. You want to wrap the `id` of the control into quotes. Say if your control ends up with id "blah_blah_text2", your javascript will look like

   ```
   show(blah_blah_text2);
   ```

   so js will try to evaluate "blah_blah_text2" as a variable, and will fail of course. Instead you want

   ```
   show('blah_blah_text2');
   ```

   so

   ```
   "show('" + text2.ClientID +"')"
   ```

Also I am not quite sure what `visible = true;` stands for. There is no such property in DOM objects as far as I know. Did you actually mean `document.getElementById(name).style.visibility = "visible"`?

Comment: inline style like `style="visible: false"` is wrong. you've to use either "display:none;" or "visibility:hidden;". the second one will leave the placeholder as it is.

Comment: Also note his javascript need to be amended to ...`document.getElementById(name).style.visibility = 'visible';`...

Answer (score 0):

> which makes text2 appear when the user puts the mouse over text1;
>   below is what I currently have.

Html *title* attribute serves this purpose.

Try this:

```
text2.Attributes.Add("title", text2.ClientID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope You are looking for this:

```
text2.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "show('" + text2.ClientID +"')");
```